# Handling null values in price column in Magento

Tags: magento

My Magento site has a problem with Special Price. In the database, the `special_price` column shows a null value, but in the Magento backend (Manage Product -> Special Price) it shows 0.00 instead of NULL.

It also shows the Special Price as 0.00 instead of the original value in the product detail page. Whenever user add product to cart it gives a price of 0.00.

How do I remove the special price of 0.00 from the backend and front-end?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this problem would be to export your products to a CSV, remove all the *nulls* or *0.00* values from the `special_price` column, i.e. set them to a blank value, and then import again.